# Regex Log Parsing - how to begin parsing lines at one event and stop parsing lines at another event?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have a log file which tracks several game events per line, however this also includes events that happen outside of 'official' game time (i.e. pregame etc). I have predefined regex patterns that can read and parse each event, and aggregates these stats, though this includes the excess stats that occur both before and after the official round.

My stat aggregation is currently fine, I am currently struggling with parsing between a range of two events. There is no explicit 'game start' event, though there is a 'round start' event, which counts for *every* round that is started during the match. Game over is simpler, as 'game over' is an event which is logged.

If I am able to read the 'round start' event, and the 'game over' event, how would I be able to *begin* reading lines in the file at the *first instance* of 'round start', and finish reading lines once game over has been triggered?

```
eg:
line 37 | trigger "(Round_Start)"  <-- begin parsing here
...
line 192 | trigger "(Round_Start)"
...
line 304 | trigger "(Round_Start)"
...
line 486 | trigger "(Round_Start)"
...
line 594 | trigger "(Game_Over)"    <-- finish parsing here
```

See some code below which may help.

```
dmgEvent_P = re.compile(r'"([\w\s]+)<.*hurt "([\w\s]+)<.*\(dmg "(\d+)"')
hpEvent_P = re.compile(r'"([\w\s]+)<.*healed "([\w\s]+)<.*\(hp "(\d+)"')
roundStart_P = re.compile(r'trigger "(Round_Start)"')
gameOver_P = re.compile(r'trigger "(Game_Over)"')



matches = dmgEvent_P.finditer(contents)
    for match in matches:
        dealer = match.group(1)
        receiver = match.group(2)
        dmg = int(match.group(3))
        modifyDMG(dealer, receiver, dmg)
matches = healthEvent_P.finditer(contents)
    for match in matches:
        dealer = match.group(1)
        receiver = match.group(2)
        hp = int(match.group(3))
        modifyHP(dealer, receiver, hp)
```

There are other ingame events being tracked but they function very similarly.

As it stands, my current code currently parses all events by reading the log's contents entirely per each regex parsing function, rather than collectively line by line. I would like to be able to collectively parse these lines within a range as I've defined above.

Comment: Escape literal parentheses in the regex.

Comment: I am using the parentheses to define the groups that I extract data from. Must they still be escaped in this context? There are no parentheses in the log entries.

Comment: If `trigger "(Round_Start)"` is your text, the parentheses must be matched with `\(` and `\)` in the pattern.

Comment: My text is ```trigger "Round_Start"```. I believe I should be fine in this instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can match `trigger "(Round_Start)"` and read all lines that do not contain  `trigger "(Game_Over)"`

```
^.*?\btrigger "\(Round_Start\)".*(?:\n(?!.*\(Game_Over\)).*)*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bIu0b0/1)

If (Game_Over) should be present after the lines, you can capture the lines before it in a capture group, and match the lines afterwards that contains (Game_Over)

```
^(.*?\btrigger "\(Round_Start\)".*(?:\n(?!.*\(Game_Over\)).*)*)\n.*?\btrigger "\(Game_Over\)"
```

The pattern matches

- `^` Start of string
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `.*?\btrigger "\(Round_Start\)".*` Match a whole line that contains trigger "(Round_Start)"
  - `(?:` Non capture group to repeat as a whole part

    - `\n(?!.*\(Game_Over\)).*` Match a newline, and the rest of the line if it does not contain (Game_Over) using a negative lookahead. If you want to exclude more lines, you can use `(?!.*(?:\(Game_Over\)|another string)`
  - `)*` Close non capture group and optionally repeat
- `)` Close capture group 1
- `\n.*?\btrigger "\(Game_Over\)"` Match a newline, and match trigger "(Game_Over)" in the line

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kKZO10/1)

**Note** to escape the parenthesis `\(` and `\)` or else`"(Round_Start)"` will not match, and only `(Round_Start)` will capture the text in a capture group.

Comment: Thank you for this! Sorry if I misunderstand it. So what the regex here does is capture all lines inbetween the two instances, which I can then return and send to be parsed?

Comment: @crkn213 Yes, the pattern first matches `trigger "(Round_Start)` and then the rest of the line. Then it optionally repeats matching all lines that do not contain `(Game_Over)` using a negative lookahead `(?!` So in this regex demo, you can see that the captured parts is highlighted in green https://regex101.com/r/kKZO10/1

Comment: Would I also be able to capture the 'Game Over' reason in the same line? The syntax would be as follows ```trigger "Game_Over" reason "(Win Limit|TimeLimit)"``` where there are two possible reasons for game end. My current regex for this is ```(.*?\btrigger "\(Round_Start\)".*(?:\n.*)*)\n.*?\btrigger "\(Game_Over\)" reason \"(Win Limit|Time Limit)\"```. Also, while the current proposed regex would not return a match within my code, though removing the ```^``` seems to have fixed that.

Comment: @crkn213 If those are the only 2 allowed reasons, then you could use `(Win Limit|TimeLimit)` to capture them, and you will have an extra capture group. If the pattern worked omitting the `^` then is could also be ok, only the match then does not start at the start of the string.